# Element not interactable when sending keys to search box

Tags: python, xml, selenium

I'm a beginner of selenium. I was trying to send value to a search box after successfully log in to a webpage. The following is the XML code for the search box:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NXe7.png)

And my code is as follows:

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)

element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#wd-searchInput > input")))

time.sleep(3)

element.send_keys("N16544699")
```

I think I can locate the search box, but the value cannot be sent to the box,the error is:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Please advise, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this xpath works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@data-automation-id='globalSearchInput']").send_keys("Your text here")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can locate the element by using your code, however, the error is still the same: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Can you try click() on the webelement before send_keys()?